# PL/SQL can you INSERT INTO (SELECT GROUP BY)?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am tasked with creating an Oracle PL/SQL procedure "summarizer" that creates a summary table (mean, median etc. for each column) from a table.

The original table (mix of numeric and categorical columns):

```
column_1 | column_2| column_3| column_4
---------------------------------------
```

The desired output:

```
table_name | column_name | mean | tally 
---------------------------------------
```

To do this, I am attempting to use a cursor that iterates over the USER_TAB_COLUMNS table (contains table_name, column_name) to INSERT the aggregations for each column_name INTO the SUMMARY_TABLE.

Here is my progress so far:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE summarizer 
IS
    CURSOR column_cursor IS
        SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE
        FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS
        WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'BANK';

BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE SUMMARY_TABLE';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE SUMMARY_TABLE (
                        table_name VARCHAR(20),
                        column_name VARCHAR(20),
                        data_type VARCHAR(20),
                        mean NUMBER,
                        tally NUMBER,
                        PRIMARY KEY (table_name, column_name))';

    FOR colname IN column_cursor LOOP
           INSERT INTO SUMMARY_TABLE
                SELECT
                colname.table_name AS table_name,
                colname.column_name AS column_name,
                colname.data_type AS data_type,
                mean(colname.column_name) AS mean,
                count(colname.column_name) AS tally
                FROM BANK
                GROUP BY table_name, column_name, data_type;
    END LOOP;
COMMIT;
END summarizer;
```

This produces the error:

```
Error report -
20/12     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
28/51     PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "DATA_TYPE": invalid identifier
```

I am unable to locate the cause of this error. I believe it could be something to do with a GROUP BY in the INSERT INTO statement. Can anyone help?

Comment: that's probably about the procedure itself. change `CREATE PROCEDURE` to `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE`

Comment: `or REPLACE`, @Cee, not `alter`.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the first issue! now I have another issue, edited above.

Comment: You don't need to drop and create summary_table (this is Oracle not SQL Server). You accomplish the same with truncate.  So "execute immediate truncate summary_table"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need *dynamic SQL* to use variables in a query string.

Consider:

```
FOR colname IN column_cursor LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
        'INSERT INTO SUMMARY_TABLE
        SELECT
            ''' || colname.table_name || ''' AS table_name,
            ''' || colname.column_name || ''' AS column_name,
            ''' || colname.data_type || ''' AS data_type,
            avg(' || colname.column_name || ') AS mean,
            count(' || colname.column_name || ') AS tally
        FROM BANK';
END LOOP;
```

Side notes:

- the constant values (table name, column name and datatype) need to be enclosed in quotes
- there is no `mean()` aggregate function in Oracle (nor in most other RDBMS): you can use `avg()` instead
- you don't actually need a `group by` clause in your `insert ... select ...` query, since the non-aggregated columns are constants

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3a6202d0adcbc7826ad66512bde98ae1)**:

```
-- create the table and insert a few records
create table bank(id int, val int);
begin
    insert into bank values(1, 1);
    insert into bank values(2, 1);
    insert into bank values(3, 1);
end;
/

-- create the summary table (it must exist since the procedure drops it)
create table summary_table(id int);

-- create the procedure
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE summarizer 
IS
    CURSOR column_cursor IS
        SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE
        FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS
        WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'BANK';

BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE SUMMARY_TABLE';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE SUMMARY_TABLE (
                        table_name VARCHAR(20),
                        column_name VARCHAR(20),
                        data_type VARCHAR(20),
                        mean NUMBER,
                        tally NUMBER,
                        PRIMARY KEY (table_name, column_name))';

    FOR colname IN column_cursor LOOP
           EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
               'INSERT INTO SUMMARY_TABLE
                SELECT
                ''' || colname.table_name || ''' AS table_name,
                ''' || colname.column_name || ''' AS column_name,
                ''' || colname.data_type || ''' AS data_type,
                avg(' || colname.column_name || ') AS mean,
                count(' || colname.column_name || ') AS tally
                FROM BANK';
    END LOOP;
COMMIT;
END summarizer;
/

-- run the procedure
begin
    summarizer;
end;
/

-- check the results
select * from summary_table
```

```
TABLE_NAME | COLUMN_NAME | DATA_TYPE | MEAN | TALLY
:--------- | :---------- | :-------- | ---: | ----:
BANK       | ID          | NUMBER    |    2 |     3
BANK       | VAL         | NUMBER    |    1 |     3
```